# Execute dynamic sql in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, dynamic

I would like to have a query like this

```
SELECT
    param1,
    param2,
    param3,
    getHidden(param1, param3)
FROM xxx
```

In which my function has to build a dynamic query, execute it and return 0 or 1.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getHidden (@param1 VARCHAR(50), @param2 INT) RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @firstSelect VARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE @query VARCHAR(1000);
    SELECT @firstSelect = restriction FROM xxxx WHERE param1 = @param1 AND param2
    SET @query = 'SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM xxx WHERE ' + @firstSelect;
    -- EXEC @query?
    RETURN 1
END
```

I'm blocked in the dynamic query execution, is there a workaround to get through this problem?

Thx,
Jeremy

EDIT : Details
In jasper ireport, I have to make a query (only one) which should be able to return and display a list of questions.
In the database, each line has a question and may have a restriction field. This field contains a WHERE constraint (example of content: BEIE_Emp_Nb = 0)
In my php program, I use this field for building my query. My final query will be:

`SELECT param1, param2 FROM questions WHERE 1 = 1 AND $constraint`
which gives me
`SELECT param1, param2 FROM questions WHERE 1 = 1 AND BEIE_Emp_Nb = 0`

I don't know if this is clear enough. The problem is the fact that I have to query the constraint field for the actual question and THEN build my query and return the result.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? I'd be surprised if there weren't a better way if you can explain in more detail.

Comment: I can't find a solution to execute @query and return the value (1 or 0

Comment: `EXEC sp_executesql @query` ?

Comment: @user1474188 That's what you're trying to do here, I can see that. I'm suggesting that you take a step back from the code and explain the actual problem you're trying to solve, which might have a better solution than the one you're implementing.

Comment: Just edited my main topic.

Comment: @user1474188 Thanks, that does make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call stored procedures, like `sp_executesql`, in a SQL Server function.
This means that you can't define and execute dynamic SQL code inside a function.
The reason is that **functions are not allowed to have side-effects** (like calling themselves and changing data or parameters, as you're doing with your dynamic SQL query, and executing something like INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE).

**Only stored procedures can call functions** and not the other way around. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx) the limitations and restrictions of functions.
You should then create a stored procedure, instead of a function, to solve your problem.

Comment: Will I be abble to call it the way I want then? (SELECT param1, EXEC proc @param1 = 'xxx' FROM mytable)

Comment: @jeremyb Yes, you will be able to execute dynamic SQL code inside a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

To execute dynamic query use `EXEC` with output variable.

```
DECLARE @nResult INT

EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@nResultNew INTEGER OUTPUT', @nResult OUTPUT

RETURN @nResult
```

Comment: You cannot call stored procedures in a SQL Server function. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx).